# Jquery UI .slider is not a function

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

In my Laravel project I'm trying to include the range slider from jQueryUI however I keep getting an error. I include both jQuery and jQueryUI. If I check the sources in the inspector both files are loaded in.

```html
<head>
...
        <!-- Styles -->
        <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
            integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var outputSpan = $('#spanOutput');
                var sliderDiv = $('#slider');

                sliderDiv.slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: 18,
                    max: 100,
                    values: [20, 30],
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        outputSpan.html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1] + ' Years');
                    },
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#txtMinAge').val(ui.values[0]);
                        $('#txtMaxAge').val(ui.values[1]);
                    }
                });

                outputSpan.html(sliderDiv.slider('values', 0) + ' - '
                    + sliderDiv.slider('values', 1) + ' Years');
                $('#txtMinAge').val(sliderDiv.slider('values', 0));
                $('#txtMaxAge').val(sliderDiv.slider('values', 1));
            });
        </script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" defer type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/myScripts.js')}}" defer type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            @include('includes.sidebar')
            @include('includes.search')
            @include('includes.faq')
            @yield('content')
            @include('includes.subscribe')
        </div>
    </body>
```

The warning I'm getting is:

```
>jQuery.Deferred exception: sliderDiv.slider is not a function TypeError: sliderDiv.slider is not a function  
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8000/:29:27)  
        at e (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:29453)  
        at t (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2:29755) 
  undefined
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
>Uncaught TypeError: sliderDiv.slider is not a function  
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):29)  
        at e (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)   
        at t (jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2)
```

Comment: The code you've shown in the question works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/sa2jhwe9/ - although you need to fix the `stop` logic to get the correct values, but it still works without any errors.

Comment: It seems that for some reason the slider is not initialized at the end of document ready. Can you try putting this into a setTimeout with a large timeout value, like 10000, so if that works, then my hypothesis would be confirmed?

Comment: @LajosArpad I did what you suggested and just got the error again after the timeout.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is something else. Can you take a look at an online demo and note what are the scripts they are including there?

Comment: The scripts are working as @RoryMcCrossan pointed out. Maybe the scripts are conflicting with one of my own scripts ? Let me try disabling my own scripts and get back at you.

Comment: @GeordiFeijens it looks more like incompatibility between jquery and its plugins, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @LajosArpad So I got it to work when I commented out `<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}" defer type="text/javascript"></script>` The thing is, the only line in app.js is `require('./bootstrap');` Any ideas why it's conflicting ? Even when I comment out the line in app.js, the error still shows up.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you're *not* seeing the error when you comment those libraries out, this would suggest that maybe there is a conflict that is interfering with jQuery UI. You may want to look at Console to see if there are any other load issues.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! Ended up fixing it by including bootstrap via the CDN in a script tag and disregarding the app.js. There were no other errors and there was only one uncommented line in the file. Still don't know what caused the problem but got it to work and that's the most important part!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a conflict with my app.js file which had only one line to include bootstrap javascript. Ended up including bootstrap javascript via the CDN.

```
  <!-- Styles -->
            <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <!-- Scripts -->
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script
            src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"
            integrity="sha256-0YPKAwZP7Mp3ALMRVB2i8GXeEndvCq3eSl/WsAl1Ryk="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            // setTimeout(function() {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                var outputSpan = $('#spanOutput');
                var sliderDiv = $('#slider');

                sliderDiv.slider({
                    range: true,
                    min: 18,
                    max: 100,
                    values: [20, 30],
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        outputSpan.html(ui.values[0] + ' - ' + ui.values[1] + ' Years');
                    },
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        $('#txtMinAge').val(ui.values[0]);
                        $('#txtMaxAge').val(ui.values[1]);
                    }
                });

                outputSpan.html(sliderDiv.slider('values', 0) + ' - '
                    + sliderDiv.slider('values', 1) + ' Years');
                $('#txtMinAge').val(sliderDiv.slider('values', 0));
                $('#txtMaxAge').val(sliderDiv.slider('values', 1));
            });
            // }, 10000);
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="{{asset('js/myScripts.js')}}" defer type="text/javascript"></script>
```